# Unable to load JavaScript array for C# web service

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have a JavaScript object in my app that has an array object, which on the server-side, is a collection of objects with two properties (Name, Value).

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here since I've been staring at it too long, but when the following code makes it to the C# web service, the CustomProperties object as an array of 4 objects.  However, each Name and Value property is null.

```
myObject.CustomProperties = [];

myObject.CustomProperties.push({ Name: "FirstName", Value: $scope.userInfo.FirstName });
myObject.CustomProperties.push({ Name: "LastName", Value: $scope.userInfo.LastName });
myObject.CustomProperties.push({ Name: "Email", Value: $scope.userInfo.Email });
myObject.CustomProperties.push({ Name: "PortalId", Value: portalId });
```

I've tried this too...

```
myObject.CustomProperties = [];

myObject.CustomProperties.push({ "Name": "FirstName", "Value": $scope.userInfo.FirstName });
myObject.CustomProperties.push({ "Name": "LastName", "Value": $scope.userInfo.LastName });
myObject.CustomProperties.push({ "Name": "Email", "Value": $scope.userInfo.Email });
myObject.CustomProperties.push({ "Name": "PortalId", "Value": portalId });
```

All of the above variables have values in the debugger, but the array must not be getting loaded right, because the web service is only showing null values.

[image]

This is the code that calls the web service. I've removed what I think are unnecessary bits though.

```
factory.callPostService("ActionName", myObject)
    .success(function (data) {
        // nothing in here happens
    })
    .error(function (data, status) {
    // this always occurs
        $scope.HasErrors = true;
        console.log("Unknown error occurred calling ActionName");
        console.log(data);
    });
```

The server-side code that I use looks pretty much identical to the rest of my classes and properties.

Here's the property as it is for the myObject in my example.

```
public List<CustomPropertyInfo> CustomProperties { get; set; }
```

And here's the CustomPropertyInfo class.

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomPropertyInfo : ICustomPropertyInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've added an additional code snippet as asked. :)

Comment: can add `$scope.userInfo` object. where did it declare

Comment: userInfo is successfully loaded in a previous web service call, and then updated in the form.  Those objects show their expected values in web developer tools

Comment: You'll need to show the code/annotation that loads the array server-side. Your client-side code is correctly producing an array with at least the given names, so if you're seeing `null` for `Name` server-side, it's a server-side problem.

Comment: Server side, the rest of the object appears to be serializing fine, and this specific object is simply a list of an object.  I've updated my question to show that property and object.

Comment: in your controller or server side class(aspx.cs) in first line of that set a breakpoint and add a watch, and watch "Request", for example "Request.From" and other property of this, and search for your data

Comment: @vahidkargar Unfortunately, it's not that simple. I'm using WebAPI, so unless you know of another place to stick a breakpoint, the serialization has already occurred by the time I can view the results.

Comment: This has got to be something that ASP.Net Web API is doing. I can verify that the JavaScript object is being sent to my app just fine using Fiddler.  Nothing is null, empty, or otherwise unexpected. And I was able to take that and successfully parse the posted JSON object in JSONFormatter.com. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused because the Json Serializer does not know how to deserialize the collection correctly.  The easiest way to resolve this is to mark the CustomPropertyInfo class with Json attributes to tell Json.Net how to handle this object.  This eliminates any confusion caused by serializing/deserializing a generic List.

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class CustomPropertyInfo : ICustomPropertyInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```